# Configure nuxt to return page with js typeError rather then returning error page

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I'm using vue and nuxt in server side rendering mode to serve my website.
My problem is that when an internal js error encountered on the page nuxt serves back an error page back which is bad for user experience and SEO.
I would prefer to handle such errors client side.

For example if I have error inside mounted hook an error page would be returned:

```
mounted () {
  console.log({}.bla.bla) // will throw typeError
}
```

Is there a way to configure nuxt to ignore such kind of errors during server side rendering so the page still would be served instead of the error nuxt page?

Comment: https://blog.lichter.io/posts/change-the-nuxtjs-server-error-page

Comment: @Aldarund, Well I don't need to customise error page I want my page to be served and handle error with toast error message client side.

Comment: And how do u see it can happen if error happens on server side and u don't handle it? Basically it means page can't be rendered. The only way is to catch up errors

Comment: @Aldarund, well html still can be served, right?
I understand that functionality would be broken but users will see at least something, also crawler bot still would be able to crawl it...

Comment: No, it won't . If you don't catch error it's can't generate html, because error happens during html generation